# Razer Blade 15 Touchpad Disabled In Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

I recently purchased a Razer Blade 15, and have installed Ubuntu 18.04. Immediately noticeable after installation: the trackpad is not working. An external mouse works just fine, but the trackpad is completly unresponsive.

To those using a Razer Blade & Ubuntu: have any of you run into this issue? If so, could you please provide the resources to get the trackpad working?

Comment: It's happening to everyone: https://insider.razer.com/index.php?threads/razer-blade-15-ubuntu-18-04-trackpad-not-working.35999/

Comment: @MosesXu It looks like there's also work being done on Ubuntu's end for this issue.
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199911